# Can't boot in ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning

I was trying to create a new partition of my current working SSD partition, but it didn't happen(I tried to shrink it). It said SSD in use and then I rebooted the system. Now I am getting this error and I can't  use Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AU. To give you any help, we’ll need to know a lot more. Can you explain (by editing your question) *exactly* what you did to try to create the new partition? It’s not clear if you tried to shrink your working partition or create a new one in unallocated space, or what tools you used. Thanks.